# I want to remove img tag on click of button from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have added here 2 functions `moveoutid()` for creating img tag on click of button and it adds image src to img tag to show image on web page, and  `moveinid()`  for removing selected image from img tag.

```
function moveoutid() {
    var sda = document.getElementById('availableFruits');
    var len = sda.length;
    var sda1 = document.getElementById('orderFruits');

    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (sda[j].selected) {
            alert(baseUrl + "/img/" + sda.options[j].value + ".jpg");
            var img1 = document.createElement('img').src = baseUrl + "/img   /" + sda.options[j].value + ".jpg";

            var di = document.getElementById('d');
            di.appendChild(img1);

            var tmp = sda.options[j].text;
            var tmp1 = sda.options[j].value;
            sda.remove(j);
            j--;
            var y = document.createElement('option');
            y.text = tmp1;
            try {
                sda1.add(y, null);
            } catch (ex) {
                sda1.add(y);
            }
        }
    }
}


function moveinid() {
    var sda = document.getElementById('availableFruits');
    var sda1 = document.getElementById('orderFruits');
    var len = sda1.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (sda1[j].selected) {

            di = document.getElementById('d');
            img1.src = baseUrl + "/img/" + sda1.options[j].value + ".jpg";
            //img.className="";

            di.removeChild(img1);

            var tmp = sda1.options[j].text;
            var tmp1 = sda1.options[j].value;
            sda1.remove(j);
            j--;
            var y = document.createElement('option');
            y.text = tmp;

            try {
                sda.add(y, null);
            } catch (ex) {
                sda.add(y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove selected `img` tag from `div` (means which ever image selected by user in dropdown list that image should be remove.)

Comment: what's this have to do with php

Comment: I don't see img1 being created in the moveinid() function. But it is being referenced. Where do you get it from?

Comment: why are you looping through an Id; Id's should be unique to the page

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the tag it sounds like you just need to show and hide that image.

```
document.getElementById('Image').style.visibility='visible';
```

If I understood correctly. Or you could even destroy the element removing it from the DOM.

Comment: but there are multiple image tag are created in div "dynamically" ,so how to take id, because we are adding image dynamically from javascript only

Comment: When you add the div dynamically add a class to it or an identifier so you can later select it and delete it.                      img1.setAttribute('id', 'uniqueId');